# Script in Vue.js component isn't executed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I created a component for my navigation bar, which I load in my header component. It is rendered and works as expected. The only problem I have is that the script, e.g. the mounted function isn't executed. That is really weird, because in the other components that works properly.

**Nav component**

```
<template>
  <div id="header-top">
    <img id="logo" src="../assets/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" draggable="false" />
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
      <router-link to="/abc">abc</router-link>
      <router-link to="/cba">cba</router-link>
      <router-link to="/def">edf</router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    let headerTop;

    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
      if (!headerTop) headerTop = document.getElementById("header-top");

      if (window.scrollY !== 0 && headerTop) {
        headerTop.classList.add("header-top-home-scrolled", "header-scrolled");
      } else if (headerTop) {
        headerTop.classList.remove("header-top-home-scrolled");
      }
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

**Header** (where I import and use the navigation)

```
<template>
    <header id="header-home">
      <Nav/>
      <div id="header-home-content">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
      </div>
    </header>
</template>

<script>
import Nav from '@/components/Nav'

export default {
  components: {
    Nav
  }
}
</script>
```

If you can spot a mistake, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know it isn't being executed? I suggest putting some console logging at the start of the function. Also make some arbitrary changes to the template to confirm it isn't a caching issue and then refresh the page to force mounting.

Comment: I did that and there was no output in the console. The problem isn't caused by the cache, I tested that, too.

Comment: Could you just confirm, did you try making some arbitrary changes to the template as I suggested? That was an important test diagnostically, not just to ensure it isn't a caching problem. Could you also check that your component only has a single `<script>` section?

Comment: Omfg, there really was a second script block under the styling.. Wow, what a stupid error by me. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to see why it's not working, I replicated the code on codepen, and it worked fine.

It's not recommended to manually manipulate the DOM, and try to avoid it wherever you can. Here's an alternate way to write that component:

```
<template>
  <div :class="headerClass">
    <img id="logo" src="../assets/img/logo.png" alt="Logo" draggable="false" />
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
      <router-link to="/abc">abc</router-link>
      <router-link to="/cba">cba</router-link>
      <router-link to="/def">edf</router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      hasBodyScrolled: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, { passive: true });
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll)
  },
  computed: {
    headerClass() {
      return {
        'header-top-home-scrolled': true,
        'header-scrolled': this.hasBodyScrolled
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onScroll() {
      this.hasBodyScrolled = window.scrollY !== 0;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here we are simply using a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to determine the class of the header. It depends on the `hasBodyScrolled` data property. The method `onScroll` will change the value of `hasBodyScrolled` to a boolean.
And in the template we simply use the computed property as class name for our header. Learn more about [class and style bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).